# One form two actions depending on which button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have two files, `preview.php` & `save.php`

```
<form id="create-template" class="form" action="" method="post">
    <p class="_50">
        <label for="t-name">Template name</label>
        <input type="text" name="t-name" class="required"/>
    </p>
    <p class="_100">
        <label for="t-html">Template HTML</label>
        <textarea id="t-html" name="t-html" class="required" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="block-actions">
        <ul class="actions-left">
            <li><a class="button red" id="reset-template" href="javascript:void(0);">Clear</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="actions-right">
            <li><div id="preview"><input type="submit" class="button" value="Preview template" onclick="return false;"></div></li>
            <li><input type="submit" class="button" value="Create template"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

Current JS:

```
$("#preview").click(function() {
    $.post('preview.php', {body:$('#t-html').val().replace(/\n/g,'<br />'), function (result) {
        //maybe use .ajax instead? 
        //open preview.php in new window
    });
});
```

How can I use the same form but have two different actions depending on what button one presses?

`Preview template` => `preview.php` => `opens to a new tab`

`Create template` => `save.php` => `posts on same page`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a click event handler for both the button and attach simultaneous ajax call with each other.

and you can use javascript to open window in new tab.

```
window.open(<url>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting "target" attribute of the form based on what button was clicked.

Change your form to the following:

```
<form id="create-template" class="form" action="" method="post" target="_blank">
    <p class="_50">
        <label for="t-name">Template name</label>
        <input type="text" name="t-name" class="required"/>
    </p>
    <p class="_100">
        <label for="t-html">Template HTML</label>
        <textarea id="t-html" name="t-html" class="required" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="block-actions">
        <ul class="actions-left">
            <li><a class="button red" id="reset-template" href="javascript:void(0);">Clear</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="actions-right">
            <li><input id="preview-form" type="submit" class="button" value="Preview template" /></li>
            <li><input type="submit" id="submit-form" class="button" value="Create template" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>​
```

And add this JavaScript:

```
$('#preview-form').click(function(ev) {
    $('#create-template').attr('action', 'preview.php');    
    $('#create-template').attr('target', '_blank');
});

$('#submit-form').click(function(ev) {
    $('#create-template').attr('action', 'submit.php');
    $('#create-template').attr('target', '');
});
​
```

I haven't tested this across all browsers, so you might want to do that.